# Pandas: parallelizing operation

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

# Generate date range for the next year
start_date = datetime.now()
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=365)
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

# Generate random integer values for the time series
num_days = len(date_range)
random_values = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=num_days)

# Create a DataFrame
data = {'Date': date_range, 'Value': random_values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def transform_dataframe(df, mult, pow):
    time.sleep(2000)
    df['value_mult'] = df['Value'] * mult
    df['value_pow'] = df['Value'] ** pow
    df = df[['Date', 'value_mult', 'value_pow']]
    return df

transforms = [(2, 3, 'set1'),
              (0.5, 2, 'set2'),
              (3, 0.5, 'set3'),
              (1.5, 2.5, 'set4')]

# Initialize an empty list to store the transformed DataFrames
transformed_dfs = []

# Apply the transformations and store the DataFrames in the list
for mult, pow, setname in transforms:
    transformed_df = transform_dataframe(df.copy(), mult, pow)
    transformed_df.rename(columns={'value_mult': f'{setname}_value_mult', 'value_pow': f'{setname}_value_pow'}, inplace=True)
    transformed_dfs.append(transformed_df)

merged_df = pd.concat(transformed_dfs, keys=[f'{setname} Transform' for _, _, setname in transforms])
```

Above is my dummy code, I don't wish to wait each function to finish computation. How can I parallelize for loop so that the computation happen in parallel and I get the same merged_df.

Comment: Does order matter?  You can certainly spin them off to threads, but there's no guarantee the threads will finish in order.

Comment: Order doesn't matter, ideally can keep date as one column and the data coming from function call in other columns

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it with threading, with the caveat that the results might be in random order:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import threading
import queue

# Generate date range for the next year
start_date = datetime.now()
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=365)
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

# Generate random integer values for the time series
num_days = len(date_range)
random_values = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=num_days)

# Create a DataFrame
data = {'Date': date_range, 'Value': random_values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def transform_dataframe(result, df, mult, pow, rename):
#    time.sleep(2000)
    df['value_mult'] = df['Value'] * mult
    df['value_pow'] = df['Value'] ** pow
    df = df[['Date', 'value_mult', 'value_pow']]
    df.rename(columns=rename, inplace=True)
    result.append(df)

transforms = [(2, 3, 'set1'),
              (0.5, 2, 'set2'),
              (3, 0.5, 'set3'),
              (1.5, 2.5, 'set4')]

# Initialize an empty list to store the transformed DataFrames
transformed_dfs = []

# Apply the transformations and store the DataFrames in the list
threads = []
for mult, pow, setname in transforms:
    rename = {'value_mult': f'{setname}_value_mult', 'value_pow': f'{setname}_value_pow'}
    t = threading.Thread( target=transform_dataframe, args=(transformed_dfs, df.copy(), mult, pow, rename ))
    t.start()
    threads.append( t )

for t in threads:
    t.join()

merged_df = pd.concat(transformed_dfs, keys=[f'{setname} Transform' for _, _, setname in transforms])
print(merged_df)
```

Comment: result passed to transform_dataframe is that shared across the thread? How does that work under the hood? If it is shared across the thread why it is not slowing things? If it is not shared why it is even passed in the function/method?

Comment: Unlike processes, all threads have access to the same memory space.  Sharing costs nothing.  I passed it to avoid using globals.  The function stands alone.  This code works -- I tried it before I posted it.

Comment: Yes, this works. My question was more in relation to GIL. I am not clear on whats happening, will relook again.

Comment: The GIL is mostly irrelevant here.  The computations will be done in numpy, which is written in C and does not have the GIL limitations.  The Python code will be limited by the GIL, but that's good -- it means we don't have to interlock the `append`.  The `df` instance is unique to each thread, so it's not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the transforms in a thread pool. This will only speed things up if there is something in the per-transform thread pool that releases the python GIL. Pandas may do that in some of its operations (but it's not well documented when) and that may happen in whatever your sleep is standing in for.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

# Generate date range for the next year
start_date = datetime.now()
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=365)
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

# Generate random integer values for the time series
num_days = len(date_range)
random_values = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=num_days)

# Create a DataFrame
data = {'Date': date_range, 'Value': random_values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def transform_dataframe(df, mult, pow):
    time.sleep(3)
    df['value_mult'] = df['Value'] * mult
    df['value_pow'] = df['Value'] ** pow
    df = df[['Date', 'value_mult', 'value_pow']]
    return df

transforms = [(2, 3, 'set1'),
              (0.5, 2, 'set2'),
              (3, 0.5, 'set3'),
              (1.5, 2.5, 'set4')]

import multiprocessing as mp, multiprocessing.pool

MAX_THREADS_FOR_TRANSFORM = 10

def df_transform_worker(mult, pow, setname):
    transformed_df = transform_dataframe(df.copy(), mult, pow)
    transformed_df.rename(columns={'value_mult': f'{setname}_value_mult', 'value_pow': f'{setname}_value_pow'}, inplace=True)
    return transformed_df


with mp.pool.Pool(max(len(transforms), MAX_THREADS_FOR_TRANSFORM)) as pool:
    merged_df = pd.concat(pool.starmap(df_transform_worker, transforms),
        keys=[f'{setname} Transform' for _, _, setname in transforms])
```

Comment: This doesn't work! not sure if you tested this?